# How to select by MAX date in CI Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, activerecord

Hi my table structure is given below

```
login_session_id, user_id, created_date, ci_cession_id, user_agent_string
```

The created_date field is mysql_date_time.

I want to get the latest row from this table (based on the `created_date` field). How to do it with CI Active record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('** YOUR TABLE HERE **');
$this->db->order_by('created_date', 'desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

This should work by selecting all columns from the table (which you'll need to specify), ordering all rows with the most recent date at the top, then limiting it to the top row only which will be the most recent entry.

Answer (score 1):

use `order_by()`

```
 $this->db->select('login_session_id, user_id, created_date, ci_cession_id, user_agent_string');
 $this->db->from("table_name");
 $this->db->order_by("created_date", "desc");
 $query = $this->db->get(); 
 return $query->result();
```

this will do the trick

> For more take a reference from [HERE](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 1):

the best way is

```
$this->db->select_max('date');
$query = $this->db->get('members');  // Produces: SELECT MAX(date) as date FROM members
return $query->result();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html